# non - measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

It seems to be a well known fact that a subset $D\subset\mathbb{R}$ that contains exactly one element in $\mathbb{Q}+x$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ is not measurable. But trying to proof it I stumbled across the following argument
$$1=\lambda(\left[ 0,1\right]\cap\mathbb{R} )=\lambda((\underset{q\in\mathbb{Q}}{\bigcup}D+q)\cap[0,1])\overset{?}{=}\underset{q\in\mathbb{Q}}{\sum}\lambda(D).$$
I don't quite understand the last equation. He argues that every element in $D$ can get pushed injectively onto the $[0,1]$ intervall and I see that, but I don't see why the resulting set (everything from $D$ projected onto $[0,1]$ calculating modulo 1) has the same masure as $D$. For sure two sets do not have te same measure becouse they are bijective only?

Thanks in advance! I am blank on measure theory, so it may be obvious, but I still don't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ is invariant by translation so $\lambda(D+q) = \lambda(D)$.

Lebesgue measure is also countably additive. Hence

$$\lambda((\underset{q\in\mathbb{Q}}{\bigcup}D+q)\cap[0,1])= \underset{q\in\mathbb{Q}}{\sum}\lambda(D + q) = \underset{q\in\mathbb{Q}}{\sum}\lambda(D)$$

For more details see [here](https://www.mathcounterexamples.net/non-measurable-set/).

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! The first equation is where my problem lies! Becouse i dont translate the whole set $D$ by some constant $c$ but every point $x\in D$ by some $c_x$ s.t. it lies in some intervall. I don't understand why lebesgue measur is invariant under that "translation".

Comment: Invariance by translation is one of the property of Lebesgue measure. It is quite natural... if not, the measure of a set would not be the same if you translate it!

Comment: Sorry if I am completely confused but if I have a set $D$ then $D+x$ has the same measure, yes, but in the proof I saw and the one you linked you take $D$ and translate every single point to some interval, i.p. you don't consider $D+x$ since you translate every point individually by some individual constant. In my head those are two separate things. Do you see where my problem lies?

Comment: I was confused it's the countably additivity. You can break up $D$ in countably many Intervalls of length one and all translate them to $[0,1]$. I got it thanks!